# TypeError: Cannot read property from sql database

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I just started working in angularJS and kind of got a hand of it, but I can't seem to read from my database, when I return data with php files (the connection to the server is double checked and correct) it cannot recognize the object with all the variables in it (data)
Here is the full error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined
>           at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AppComponent.html:26)
>           at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11940)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11312)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11490)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11313)
>           at callWithDebugContext (core.js:12204)
>           at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:11882)
>           at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges
>   (core.js:9692)
>           at core.js:5086
>       View_AppComponent_0 @ AppComponent.html:26

here is my full html main file:

```html
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | AngularJS Tutorial with PHP - Fetch / Select Data from Mysql Database</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center">AngularJS Tutorial with PHP - Fetch / Select Data from Mysql Database</h3>  
                <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="displayData()">  
                     <label>First Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="firstname" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Last Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="lastname" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="insertData()" value="ADD"/>  
                     <br /><br />  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>First Name</th>  
                               <th>Last Name</th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <tr ng-repeat="x in names">  
                               <td>{{x.first_name}}</td>  
                               <td>{{x.last_name}}</td>  
                          </tr>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){  
      $scope.insertData = function(){  
           $http.post(  
                "insert.php",  
                {'firstname':$scope.firstname, 'lastname':$scope.lastname}  
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);  
                $scope.firstname = null;  
                $scope.lastname = null;  
                $scope.displayData();  
           });  
      }  
      
      $scope.displayData = function(){  
           $http.get("select.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
        
                $scope.names = data;  
                
           });  
      }  
 });  
 </script>  
<pre>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**Also here is my select.php:**

```
<?php  
 //select.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("den1.mssql5.gear.host", "testiranje", "nijebitno@", "testiranje");  
 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_user";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: you should initialize `$scope.names = []` in controller to handle this kind of error. if this not working check `data` in `console.log(data)`.

Comment: add `console.log(data)` above `$scope.names = data;  `

Comment: @AndrejBatarilo Can you create on stackblitz.com in Angular 5 and update the question